# Installing ubuntu 18.04 by removing windows 8.1

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, windows-8

I just need to install ubuntu 18.04 by removing windows 8.1 from my machine. Which option will be good for me? creating partitions during installation or simply clicking on 'erase everything and install ubuntu' because I don't have much knowledge about creating partitions during ubuntu installation.
I will be very grateful if you will look forward towards the matter cand do the needful.
thanks.

Comment: for a new install take ubuntu 20.04. this is the current LTS.

Answer (score 2):

"Erase everything and install Ubuntu"  will do what you want - erase the entire disk and use it for Ubuntu.

The remainder of my answer is for future readers, elaborating on the case where other partitions that need to be preserved exist on disk. Then it will be easiest to first remove the Windows partition using partition software, e.g. "Gparted" or "Disks" started from within the live session. You then can start the installer from the live session, and select the option to use the free space.

Finally, the installer has the option "Something Else". That puts you in manual control. The option brings you in a partition editor, where you still can remove e.g. the Windows partition, then create one or more partitions as you see fit. This option is more technical than the previous two options, where an automated default configuration is set up.

Comment: will the option "erase everything and install ubuntu" can cause any harm to my hard disk?

Comment: The term "harm" is vague: The option will NOT cause physical damage to your hard disk. The option WILL permanently erase all current data and files on that disk. "Erase everything" means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your system is set up. Are there any files that you want/need to keep on your Windows partition? Is this the only partition on your disk you can see? Yes. Resize your windows parttion and create another partition on which you can keep your files.                                                                                                 Do you have documents/photos/videos on another partition than your Windows Operating System ( like a 'D-drive" ) ?                                                                                                                                                                      Than I would say choose 'Something Else' while installing Ubuntu. Wipe/format your Windows ( C-drive ) to Ext4 and use that for Ubuntu Operating System ( '/' ) and use your D-drive ( NTFS ) with your documents as '/home'. Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS partitions.                                                                                                 The small partition where your windows bootloader lives ( normally hidden, so you cannot see it ) as '/boot'.    I hope this makes any sense to you.